# Response.Flush breaking Page Caching

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching

I have some code that is used to replace certain page output with other text.  The way I accomplish this is by setting the Response.Filter to a Stream, Flushing the Response, and then reading that Stream back into a string.  From there I can manipulate the string and output the resulting code.  You can see the basic code for this over at [Render a view as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string) .

However, I noticed that Page Caching no longer works after the first Response.Flush call.

I put together a simple ASP.NET WebApp as an example.  I have a Default.aspx with an @OutputCache set for 30 seconds.  All this does is output DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString().  I override Render.  If I do a Response.Flush (even after the base.Render) the page does not get cached.  This is regardless of any programmatic cacheability that I set.

So it seems that Response.Flush completely undermines any page caching in use.  Why is this?

*extra credit*: is there a way to accomplish what I want (render output to a string) that will not result in Page Cache getting bypassed?

**ASPX Page:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestCacheVsFlush._Default" %>
<%@ OutputCache Duration="30" VaryByParam="none" %>
<%= DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() %>
```

**Code-behind (Page is Cached):**

```
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        base.Render(writer);
    }
```

**Code-behind (Page is not cached):**

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    base.Render(writer);
    Response.Flush();
}
```

**Code-behind (Page still is not cached):**

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    base.Render(writer);
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Server);
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30));
    Response.Flush();
}
```

Comment: edit: I updated the title to be more descriptive of the problem

Comment: This is a great question.  Digging through reflector, I don't find any obvious connections to flushing and caching.... wish I could spend more time on it right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I think I have a partial answer for you.

From [here](http://blogs.iis.net/ksingla/archive/2006/11/16/caching-in-iis7.aspx):

> Output cache module populates the
>   IHttpCachePolicy intrinsic in
>   BeginRequest stage if a matching
>   profile is found. Other modules can
>   still change cache policy for the
>   current request which might change
>   user-mode or kernel mode caching
>   behavior. Output cache caches 200
>   responses to GET requests only. **If
>   some module already flushed the
>   response by the time request reaches
>   UpdateRequestCache stage or if headers
>   are suppressed, response is not cached
>   in output cache module**.

That article is IIS7 specific, so not sure how this translates across to other versions, but it's probably similar.  `UpdateRequestCache` is one of the [HttpApplication pipeline events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188942.aspx), and it occurs after an IHttpHandler (e.g. your Page object) has finished handling the request.

So... it doesn't look good for performing a flush inside your Page.

Comment: FYI, this is happening in IIS6 too.